# Custom plugin for Elasticsearch to change the default relevancy

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, ranking-functions

I am currently using Elasticsearch and there are few things I have noticed about the ranks of the search results, which led me to think about whether there is a way to create plugins/script for ES, which can be used to modify the current scoring algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a custom Java plugin for that, use [function score queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), or [scripted similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity) (which just came out this week).

If you can I would use the two later methods; writing a custom plugin should only be required very rarely.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the blog **[A Gentle Intro to Function Scoring](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-function-scoring)** which describes ranking of videos on a website using a combination of textual relevance and the videos popularity on a site.

To modify the scoring algorithm the Elasticsearch provides **[script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score), [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and [Decay Function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay).**